# Difference between date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

i am trying to get the difference with 2 dates in a special format but get an error message.
This is my code:

```
from dateutil import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
def diff_date(date1, date2):
    date_diff = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
    date = [f'{abs(date_diff.years)} ans ' if abs(date_diff.years)>0 else str(), 
            f'{abs(date_diff.months)} mois ' if abs(date_diff.months)>0 else str(), 
            f'{abs(date_diff.days)} days' if abs(date_diff.days)>0 else str()]
    return ''.join(date)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date1' : pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=15, freq="d"), 
                   'date2' : pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=15, freq="m")
                   }
                  )
df['ecart'] = diff_date(df['date1'], df['date2'])
```

the error message is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I don't know why...

I expected to get the difference of date with my function.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're trying to use a pandas `DataFrame` object as input for a `relativedelta` instance. `relativedelta` can be called in different ways, and what you're trying to achieve is possible by giving `datetime.datetime` inputs.
Read more in the [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) docs and the [`dateutils.relativedelta`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-6a1472b7c74e5b8bab7784f11214250d34e09aa5) docs, so you can call them correctly if you need to do this again sometime.

I'm not sure how you'd prefer this to be formatted, but here's an example that should help you fix your problem, reusing your own code :

```py
from dateutil import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

def diff_date(date1, date2):
    date_diff = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
    date = [f'{abs(date_diff.years)} ans ' if abs(date_diff.years)>0 else str(), 
            f'{abs(date_diff.months)} mois ' if abs(date_diff.months)>0 else str(), 
            f'{abs(date_diff.days)} days' if abs(date_diff.days)>0 else str()]
    return ''.join(date)


print(diff_date(datetime(2000,1,1)),datetime(2000,1,31)) 
# first dates in your original DataFrame object
```

The way you wrote it tells me you're trying to get differences between lists of dates, which can be done by using a for-loop (that doesn't have to be implemented in your `diff_date` function directly).